# Count unique entries based on previous groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

Trying to find unique values in each group, however with a look back at the previously grouped items. It will be group by time, so if previous time block had the unique value it should not appear in the next time block. Lookback should span all previous time blocks. So at time 2, it looks at time 0 and 1, while at time 10 it looks back at time 0 to 9.

I am also looking to do this dynamically, without manually offsetting each time block with a subquery, as time here is continuous and not discrete data set.

Sample data:

```
2018-03-25 00:00:00.000, 123
2018-03-25 00:00:00.000, 231
2018-03-26 00:00:00.000, 234
2018-03-26 00:00:00.000, 123
2018-03-27 00:00:00.000, 123
2018-03-27 00:00:00.000, 231
2018-03-27 00:00:00.000, 234
2018-03-27 00:00:00.000, 432
```

Sample output:

```
2018-03-25 00:00:00.000, 2
2018-03-26 00:00:00.000, 1
2018-03-27 00:00:00.000, 1
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output data for clarity about your requirements and issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you can consider that if the value exists in any past group, it should be excluded from the results set.

I think this kind of approach should help you:

```
select groupped.t, count(*) from
(select distinct base.t, base.v from foo as base where v not in 
  (
  select u.v from foo as u where u.t < base.t
  )
) as groupped group by groupped.t;
```

Heres also a fiddle. Hope this helps. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a65e/1

Comment: So when i expand the fiddler to more value it works well, when I try to replicate such results with timestamp, i get total of unique values much less than there are unique values. WIll try further, but this seems to do it at high level

Comment: Hmm, which date time type are u using? I tested it as well with dateime2  and even assuming that the time precision is not exact: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ba65/1